# How to load an older version of gpt.js file

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ad-manager, google-ads-script, google-publisher-tag

To load latest version of gpt.js we need to add

```
https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js
```

How can i load older version of gpt.js in my html file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like older versions of the GTP librairy are hosted this way : securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/**version**/gpt.js

Sample :
https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/v2022-12-05/gpt.js

Versions list is [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/versions).
Versions release notes are [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/release-notes).

Be careful when you use past versions of the librairy as :

> All changes to the GPT library are thoroughly tested before release. Additionally, releases are rolled out to users gradually to further protect against unexpected regressions. If a regression is spotted at any point during a rollout, the entire release can be quickly abandoned before it reaches all users.